# make height of each children in flexbox equal no matter of less or more content

Tags: html, css

i used align-items:stretch, but it is just making any effect on row class children to take full height so that no matter of inside content all should look of same size.  inside parent(cont) I have given align-items stretch its not working to put every child of same height.
i used align-items:stretch, but it is just making any effect on row class children to take full height so that no matter of inside content all should look of same size.  inside parent(cont) I have given align-items stretch its not working to put every child of same height.

```css
.cont{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.row{
    width: 32%;
    align-items: stretch;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 425px){
    .row + .row {
        margin-left: 2%;
    }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 425px){
   .cont{
       display: block;
       align-content: center;
   }
   
   .row + .row{
       margin-top: 2%;
   }

    .row{ 
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.t1{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 19px;

}
.t2{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
}

.t3{
    color: grey;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="sear-res">
                        <div class="t1">
                            Customer acquition campaign
                        </div>
                        <div class="t2">
                            @customer-acquisition
                        </div>
                        <div class="t3">
                            Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
                        </div>
                        <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
                        <br />
                        <hr />
                        <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0"
                                max="10" />
                            <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="sear-res">
                        <div class="t1">
                            Customer acquition campaign
                        </div>
                        <div class="t2">
                            @customer-acquisition
                        </div>
                        <div class="t3">
                            Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
                        </div>
                        <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
                        <br />
                        <hr />
                        <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0"
                                max="10" />
                            <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><div class="row">
                    <div class="sear-res">
                        <div class="t1">
                            Customer acquition campaign
                        </div>
                        <div class="t2">
                            @customer-acquisition
                        </div>
                        <div class="t3">
                            Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
                            Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
                            Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
                        </div>
                        <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
                        <br />
                        <hr />
                        <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0"
                                max="10" />
                            <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

You have removed just `align-items: center;` from `.cont` because by default it `align-items: strech;` which we needed and

Remove `align-items: stretch;` from `.row` because its parent property it will not work in flex child.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/wyg0vhnz/2/

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 425px) {
  .row+.row {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 425px) {
  .cont {
    display: block;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .row+.row {
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
  .row {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.t1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.t2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.t3 {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
        Excuse yourself
      </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
        Excuse yourself
      </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21 Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21 Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
        Excuse yourself
      </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `align-items: strech` on the flex parent:

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  align-items: strech;
  background-color: pink;
}

.row {
  width: 32%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 425px) {
  .row+.row {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 425px) {
  .cont {
    display: block;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .row+.row {
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
  .row {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.t1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.t2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.t3 {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21 Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21 Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or try using CSS grid:

```css
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 425px) {
  .row+.row {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 425px) {
  .cont {
    display: block;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .row+.row {
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
  .row {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.t1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.t2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.t3 {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sear-res">
      <div class="t1">
        Customer acquition campaign
      </div>
      <div class="t2">
        @customer-acquisition
      </div>
      <div class="t3">
        Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21 Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21 Team to come up with strategies to win over customer by end of FY21
      </div>
      <button class="res-3">
                            Excuse yourself
                        </button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <div class="res-4"><strong>Attendees</strong>: john@example.com</div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Select member" class="member" name="member" min="0" max="10" />
        <button type="submit" class="res-5">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```